# Azure devops pipeline is throwing error installing node js

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I am creating an Azure Devops pipleline , here is my pipeline -

```
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu 16.04

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0  
  inputs:
    versionSpec: ‘14.x’
  displayName: ‘TASK | Install Node.js 14.x ’
```

But I am getting following error -

```
Starting: ‘TASK | Install Node.js 14.x ’
==============================================================================
Task         : Node.js tool installer
Description  : Finds or downloads and caches the specified version spec of Node.js and adds it to the PATH
Version      : 0.186.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/node-js
==============================================================================
Downloading: https://nodejs.org/dist/v0.9.0/node-v0.9.0-linux-x64.tar.gz
Downloading: https://nodejs.org/dist/v0.9.0/win-x64/node.exe
Downloading: https://nodejs.org/dist/v0.9.0/node.exe
Downloading: https://nodejs.org/dist/v0.9.0/node.lib
Caching tool: node 0.9.0 x64

[error]Directory does not exist: /opt/hostedtoolcache/node/0.9.0/x64/bin

Finishing: ‘TASK | Install Node.js 14.x ’
```

Not sure whats going wrong here. I have tested the same with versionSpec : 12.x, 10.x etc, but no luck

Answer (score 2):

You have wrong characters `’`

Please use this `'`

```
  - task: NodeTool@0  
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '14.x'
    displayName: 'TASK | Install Node.js 14.x '
```

Comment: I don't think that is the issue since in my editor the character is ', that might have been placed wrong while copying to StackOverFlow

Comment: Well, I copy posted your code and I got the same error. Changed characters and it is ok now. Give a try and check on your own. Just copy paste mine code.